# How to uppercase/lowercase the ending 's' in plural acronyms

Tags: fonts, acronyms, capitalization

I'm using a template that somebody else has created, so I don't know if the default LaTeX acronym option is to upper- or lowercase the ending 's', but I would like to have it lowercase. Currently it is giving uppercase.

I think these are the options being used in the template regarding acronyms:

```
\usepackage[printonlyused,nohyperlinks]{acronym}
\renewcommand{\acsfont}[1]{{\scshape \MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
```

Do I need to add another line here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is if not a bug, at least a lack of planning on the part of the `acronym` package. When you define `\acsfont`, this gets applied to the acronym and the added plural, and there is no built-in hook to make the plural different.  The simplest solution is to comment out the `\acsfont` command, but this will make your acronyms fully upper case, which may not be what you want (although this makes the distinction between the acronym and its plural much clearer, IMO.)

Anyway, here's a version that will do what you want. For comparison, I've also shown the version without the small caps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused,nohyperlinks]{acronym}
\usepackage{textcase}
\renewcommand{\acsfont}[1]{{\scshape \MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\AC@acsp[1]{%
  \ifcsname fn@#1@PS\endcsname
  \csname fn@#1@PS\endcsname
  \else
  \AC@acs{#1}\normalfont s%
  \fi
}

\makeatother
\newacro{VP}{Verb Phrase}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{With small caps:} \acsp{VP} are \aclp{VP}. 
\paragraph{Without small caps:} 
\renewcommand{\acsfont}[1]{#1}
\acsp{VP} are \aclp{VP}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks that looks more preferable. What does the first renewcommand do and what will happen if I just take it out? Your code works, but I am getting (and skipping) this error:
! LaTeX Error: \AC@acsp undefined.

Comment: The first `\renewcommand` defines the font properties for acronyms.  If you leave it out, you won't need my modified code at all. Since you didn't post a minimal document as in my answer, it's hard to tell if there are other things being done by your actual template. You *shouldn't* get any error.  Do you get it when you compile *my* document, or only in yours?

Comment: I get the error in both cases. Perhaps my packages are not up to date. Will I get the same functionality if I just comment out the renewcommand?

Comment: Perhaps they are.  I'm using `acronym.sty 2010/09/08 v1.36` from TeXLive 2011 (you can see this by putting `\listfiles` at the beginning of the document and checking the log file.)  But yes, if you are happy with the uppercase acronyms, then you should be able to comment out the `\renewcommand{acsfont}...` from your document and not use my code at all.

Comment: Thanks.  this did it for me, on acronym.sty `2015/03/21 v1.41` (ubuntu 14.04).

One thing of note (using the same preamble): when I have special plural short forms defined, like `\acrodef{OS}[OS's]{Operating Systems}`, then, the final pluralizing s is the same shape as the preceding S, so it looks like `... blah blah OS'S are fun.` (instead of `OS's are fun`)

There is prob an equivalent fn that can be monkey patched for custom plurals?

Similarly, if I wanted to have the plural of OS as OSes, could I selectively apply the overridden function you provided for a single macro definition?